# How to inject controller into WebApp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am building a library that is supposed to add features into an aspnetcore WebApp.

My goal is to add Controllers written in the library to respond to requests on specific routes on the WebApp itself.

The first thing I've done is to write an extension method as such:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomLibrary(this IApplicationBuilder app) 
{
  if (app == null) 
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
  }
  //Here I want to hookup the routes to respond using my controller
}
```

Given that piece of code, I can now run `app.UseCustomLibrary()` from `Program.cs`.

Now, hooking up the actual controller to respond turns out to be not an easy task.

Things I've tried:

- Using Custom Middleware:

  ```
    public class MyCustomMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public MyCustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("expectedpath"))
            {
                //Manually handle the request.
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
  ```

Even though that kind of works, that doesn't really hookup the controller. Instead I can handle the request manually. I dislike that because I now have to rewrite the controller into some kind of handler. That forces to abandon the nice controller structure of automatically determining the route using area/controller/action pattern. So this is currently my plan B.

- Using Custom IApplictionFeatureProviders:

  ```
    internal class MyCustomFeatureProvider : IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>
    {
        public void PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, ControllerFeature feature)
        {
            if (!feature.Controllers.Contains(typeof(CustomController).GetTypeInfo()))
            {
                feature.Controllers.Add(typeof(CustomController).GetTypeInfo());
            }
        }
    }
  ```

Then I would slightly modify the extension method to be call that provider as such:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomLibrary(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Services.AddMvc().PartManager.FeatureProviders.Add(new MyCustomFeatureProvider());
    return builder;
}
```

I was trying to copy what Microsoft.Identity library does in how it adds the "AccountController". Unfortunately that also doesn't work. The controller actions are never called for some reason.

I have also tried using that in conjunction with the middleware, by replacing the invoke method of the middleware with the following:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Features.Set<IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature>>(new MyCustomFeatureProvider());

    await _next(context);
}
```

Again, that simply does nothing and the controller actions are never called.

I've also tried calling `app.MapControllerRoute` from my extension method, but it doesn't work as well for a reason that I cannot understand. It seems the controller is not even registered so it is never called.

I am willing to provide more details. I know there must be a way to do that, since it is used all the time in Microsoft.Identity and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication to respond to authentication callbacks from IdPs for example. So there must be a way to do what I want.

Comment: Hi, what is your scenario? Why you custom an extension to inject a controller?

Comment: The library I am building integrates with a product that is going to send periodic callback requests after you initiate a request to it. So I need to be able to respond to those callback requests to update the repository. I can't expect everyone using the library to write that code, it defeats the purpose of the library altogether.